# Azure DevOps: Grant permissions for an organizational level group to be able to contribute to all existing projects

Tags: azure, security, tfs, permissions, devops

I'm trying to find a way to grant access for a one group at Azure DevOps organizational level to be able to contribute to all projects work items. Just work items, no code/builds/pipelines permissions.

I've tried to put that group under Project Valid Users, as this group is under Readers and Contributors, but somehow it doesn't work.

Would somebody had this problem and could suggest a solution?

Many thanks!

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Hi, still working on this. Will let you know asap!

Comment: Sorry to interrupt, how is things going?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to find a way to grant access for a one group at Azure DevOps organizational level to be able to contribute to all projects work items. Just work items, no code/builds/pipelines permissions.

We could set the permission to restrict access to code. We could add Group rules and set Access level as **Stakeholder** to restrict access to code:

Organization Settings-> Users> Group rules->Add a group rule:

[image]

This permission setting will restrict access to code.

But we could not set permission for an organizational level group to restrict access to builds/pipeline. To resolve this issue, we have to set the security of the pipeline. We could not set it for all projects.

Comment: Yes, this makes complete sense - thank you! But my main question is - how to grant access for an organizational level group, to be able to access all projects and actually not limiting them at all. In other words, provide that group Contributors access, but not Project Collection Admin acess.

Comment: @EdvinasPerminas, But you said be able to contribute to all projects work items. Just work items, `no code/builds/pipelines permissions`， which is completely different from the problem described in your comment. So what is your real problem?

Comment: Actually yes, when I posted this - I thought this could be a main point of interest. The real problem is - I want to grant specific group of people contributors access to all existing private projects. Sorry about the confusion!

Comment: @EdvinasPerminas, Thanks for your clarification. If you want to grant specific group of people contributors access to all existing private projects, you just need set the Access level as **Basic** instead of Stakeholder in above answer. We could not set the contributors permissions for all projects, that is for one project.

Comment: Okay, so let's say I have a global permission, say 'Team A'. I would probably would need to go in each project and manually add it to project's Contributors permissions group, right?

Comment: @EdvinasPerminas, If you want set the Contributors permissions, you have to  go in each project and manually, otherwise, you need add them to Project Collection Administrators group. Besides, if you just make those people to access all project in your ORG, you just need set access level as **Basic**.

Comment: Does this mean 'Basic' access level grants access to Private projects as well? I thought Private projects are private for a reason?